# Compare 2 dictionaries for matching times

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two dictionaries both containing times, one of events on each day, and the other with a students free times during the day. I am trying to match them up but it seems as though I have done something wrong as they wont match.
my first dictionary is this :

```
event_dates = {} #dictionary to store event dates and time
df = pd.read_html('https://www.dcu.ie/students/events')[0]['Event date']
df = df.str.replace('([a-zA-Z]+ \d+, |\s+(?=\s))', '')
df = df.str.split("-")
event_dates.update(df)
```

this is just something to see all the events times :

```
for key in event_dates.values():
    key = key[0]
    print("Event starts at:", key)
```

and this is how it comes out

Event starts at: 09:00

Event starts at: 12:45

Event starts at: 17:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:15

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 14:00

Event starts at: 17:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:15

Event starts at: 18:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 15:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:00

Event starts at: 13:00

for my other dictionary

```
free_times = []
for column in df3:
    free_times.append({column:df3[df3[column].isna()].index.drop_duplicates().to_list()})
```

this is an example of how it comes out

[{'Mon': ['8:00', '10:00', '12:00', '13:00', '15:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00']}, {'Tue': ['8:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00']}, {'Wed': ['8:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00']}, {'Thu': ['8:00', '9:00', '12:00', '13:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00', '21:00']}, {'Fri': ['8:00', '9:00', '10:00', '11:00', '12:00', '13:00', '14:00', '15:00', '16:00', '17:00', '18:00', '19:00', '20:00',
'21:00']}]

and this is how i am trying to check them

```
if key == free_times:
    print("There is an event on")
else:
    print("There are no events on")
```

any questions please feel free to ask.

Comment: Please offer a minimal reproducible example. And please paste the dictionaries as text not as a screenshot. Also, explain more of what you mean by "match up." Do you want to pair an event to every day that has a matching time?

Comment: sorry what would you like a minimal reproducible example of? and by match up I mean if the student has a free slot on a Friday from lets say 11:00 - 12:00 I need to check if there is an event taking place at that time as well thanks

Comment: So what you are trying to do fundamentally is take a whole bunch of event start and end times and figure out where the free time is? And you want to produce a dictionary that's like `{"Mon": ["9:00", "10:00"], ...}` that signifies there is free time from 9:00 to 10:00?

Comment: Yes that’s what I am trying to do and compare these event times to when a student has a free slot on their timetable so they can attend this